# R shiny dynamic UI in insertUI

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny application where I would like to add a UI element using an action button and then have that inserted ui be dynamic.

Here is my current ui file:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  div(id="placeholder"),
  actionButton("addLine", "Add Line")
))
```

and server file:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$addLine, {
    num <- input$addLine
    id <- paste0("ind", num)
    insertUI(
      selector="#placeholder",
      where="beforeBegin",
      ui={
         fluidRow(column(3, selectInput(paste0("selected", id), label=NULL, choices=c("choice1", "choice2"))))
      })
  })

})
```

If `choice1` is selected within the specific ui element, I would like to add a `textInput` to the row. If `choice2` is selected within the ui element, I would like to add a `numericInput`.

While I generally understand how to create reactive values that change in response to user input, I don't know what to do here because I do not know how to observe an element that has not been created yet and that I do not know the name of. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Code**

This can be easily solved with [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html):

```
library(shiny)

row_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           selectInput(ns("type_chooser"), 
                       label = "Choose Type:", 
                       choices = c("text", "numeric"))
    ),
    column(9,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder"))
    )
  )
} 

row_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  return_value <- reactive({input$inner_element})
  ns <- session$ns
  output$ui_placeholder <- renderUI({
    type <- req(input$type_chooser)
    if(type == "text") {
      textInput(ns("inner_element"), "Text:")
    } else if (type == "numeric") {
      numericInput(ns("inner_element"), "Value:", 0)
    }
  })

  ## if we later want to do some more sophisticated logic
  ## we can add reactives to this list
  list(return_value = return_value) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(  
  div(id="placeholder"),
  actionButton("addLine", "Add Line"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  handler <- reactiveVal(list())
  observeEvent(input$addLine, {
    new_id <- paste("row", input$addLine, sep = "_")
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = row_ui(new_id)
    )
    handler_list <- isolate(handler())
    new_handler <- callModule(row_server, new_id)
    handler_list <- c(handler_list, new_handler)
    names(handler_list)[length(handler_list)] <- new_id
    handler(handler_list)
  })

  output$out <- renderPrint({
    lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      handle()
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Explanation**

A module is, well, a modular piece of code, which you can reuse as often as you want without bothering about unique names, because the module takes care of that with the help of `namespaces`.

A module consists of 2 parts:

1. A `UI` function
2. A `server` function

They are pretty much like the normal `UI` and  `server` functions, with some things to keep in mind:

- `namespacing`: within the server you can access elements from the `UI` as you would do normally, i.e. for instance `input$type_chooser`. However, at the `UI` part, you have to `namespace` your elements, by using `NS`, which returns a function which you can conveniently use in the rest of the code. For this the `UI` function takes an argument `id` which can be seen as the (unique) namespace for any instance of this module. The element `ids` must be unique within the module and thanks to the namespace, they will be also unique in the whole app, even if you use several instances of your module.
- `UI`: as your `UI` is a function, which only has *one*  return value, you must wrap your elements in a `tagList` if you want to return more than one element (not needed here).
- `server`: you need the `session` argument, which is otherwise optional. If you want your module to communicate with the main application, you can pass in a (reactive) argument which you can use as usual in your module. Similarly, if you want your main application to use some values from the module you should return reactives as shown in the code. If you ened to creat `UI` elements from your server function you also need to namespace them and you cann acces the namespacing function via  `session$ns` as shown.
- `usage`: to use your module you insert the `UI` part in your main app by calling the function with an unique `id`. Then you have to call `callModule` to make the server logic work, where you pass in the same `id`. The return value of this call is the `returnValue` of your module server function and can be sued to work with values from within the module also in the main app.

This explains modules in a nutshell. A very good tutorial which explains modules in much more detail and completeness can be found [here.](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

Comment: Thanks, solves my problem perfectly. Seems like I definitely need to learn how modules work!

Comment: It turns out that modules have solved a lot of my existing shiny problems, including ones that I had given up on- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could either use `insertUI()` or `renderUI()`. `insertUI()` is great if you want to add multiple uis of the same kind, but i think that doesnt apply to you.
I think you either want to add a numeric or a text input not both.

Therefore, i would suggest using `renderUI()`:

```
  output$insUI <- renderUI({
      req(input$choice)
      if(input$choice == "choice1") return(fluidRow(column(3,
         textInput(inputId = "text", label=NULL, "sampleText"))))
      if(input$choice == "choice2") return(fluidRow(column(3, 
         numericInput(inputId = "text", label=NULL, 10, 1, 20))))
  })
```

[image]

If you prefer to use `insertUI()` you can use:

```
observeEvent(input$choice, {
  if(input$choice == "choice1") insUI <- fluidRow(column(3, textInput(inputId 
                                = "text", label=NULL)))
  if(input$choice == "choice2") insUI <- fluidRow(column(3, 
                                numericInput(inputId = "text", label=NULL, 10, 1, 20)))

  insertUI(
    selector="#placeholderInput",
    where="beforeBegin",
    ui={
      insUI
    })
})
```

and on ui side: `div(id="placeholderInput")`.

Full code reads:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  div(id="placeholderChoice"),
  uiOutput("insUI"),
  actionButton("addLine", "Add Line")
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$addLine, {
    insertUI(
      selector="#placeholderChoice",
      where="beforeBegin",
      ui={
        fluidRow(column(3, selectInput(inputId = "choice", label=NULL, 
                 choices=c("choice1", "choice2"))))
      })
  })

  output$insUI <- renderUI({
      req(input$choice)
      if(input$choice == "choice1") return(fluidRow(column(3,
         textInput(inputId = "text", label=NULL, "sampleText"))))
      if(input$choice == "choice2") return(fluidRow(column(3, 
         numericInput(inputId = "text", label=NULL, 10, 1, 20))))
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this, I appreciate it. This is a little different than what I am trying to do. I would like the "Add Line" button to insert a choice, value pair every time it is clicked. So for every selectInput widget, a corresponding either textInput or numericInput

Comment: So if I clicked the button 3 times, there would be 3 separate pairs of widgets (other than the button). Each one of them would show a textInput or a numericInput based on the choice of the selectInput (independent of each other)

Comment: hmm, i am not sure i will find time for that the next days. That wasnt clear from your question to me. But i guess @thotal provides an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I unfortunately cannot comment on answers yet, but I think someone finding this question like me might want to know this: @thotal's answer worked for me except one line: `new_handler <- callModule(row_server, new_id)` gave me an error: "Warning: Error in module: unused arguments (childScope$output, childScope)"

I looked around and found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400790/error-in-modulechildscopeinput-childscopeoutput-childscope-unused-ar), which gave the solution of basically using `new_handler <- row_server(new_id)`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).