# Return input as list in reactive shiny - dynamic UI in insert UI

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the code from a previous solution [R shiny dynamic UI in insertUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55461532/r-shiny-dynamic-ui-in-insertui)

In my app right now, the inputs are rendered by the server and displayed as different elements/rows, like this

```
$row_1
[1] "LV1" "x1" "x2" "x3"

$row_2
[1] "LV2" "x4" "x5" "x6"
```

I am actually hoping to get something like this instead:

```
"LV1" "x1" "x2" "x3"
"LV2" "x4" "x5" "x6"
```

I tried a few things but I'm unsure as to how to change the `handle()` functions to get the output I want.

*Screenshots and code:*

If you try running the shiny app, you will see this:

[image]

Click on `+ LV` button and then simply select `LV1` and then multi-select `x1` `x2` `x3` and so on.

This is how it would look like with the output:

[image]

Here's the complete code

```
library(shiny)

newlist <- as.list(c("LV1", "LV2", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"))

row_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
 
     column(2,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder"))),
      column(2, 
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder2"))
    )
  )
} 

row_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  return_value <- reactive({c(input$variable1, input$variable2)})
  ns <- session$ns
  output$ui_placeholder <- renderUI({
 
      selectInput(ns("variable1"), "LV:", choices = c(' ', newlist), selected = NULL)
      
  })
  
  output$ui_placeholder2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(ns("variable2"), "Ind:", choices = c(' ', newlist), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
   list(return_value = return_value) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(  
  div(id="placeholder"),
  actionButton("addLine", "+ LV"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out"),
  verbatimTextOutput("listout5")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  handler <- reactiveVal(list())
  observeEvent(input$addLine, {
    new_id <- paste("row", input$addLine, sep = "_")
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = row_ui(new_id)
    )
    handler_list <- isolate(handler())
    new_handler <- callModule(row_server, new_id)
    handler_list <- c(handler_list, new_handler)
    names(handler_list)[length(handler_list)] <- new_id
    handler(handler_list)
  })
  
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      handle()
    })
  })
  
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
output$out <- renderPrint({
    invisible(lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      cat(paste0(paste0(handle(), collapse = " "), "\n"))
    }))
  })
```

`handle()` returns a list, the first call to `paste0` creates one string, the second `paste0` adds a new line so that all values from one module are on the same line. `invisible` prevents that the return value from `lapply` gets printed (only the sideeffect from `cat` is printed)

Comment: Thanks for usefull example. Do you know how to make that list we are creating is of the form:
```$LV
[1] 'x1', 'x2', 'x3'
$LV2
[1] 'x4', 'x5', 'x6'```
That is, instead of generic names ```row_1, row_2```, inserted in first LV window is treated as name of the element in the list?