# Error in module(childScope$input, childScope$output, childScope, ...): unused arguments (childScope$output, childScope)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to understand why I am getting this error. The goal is to have the module render mtcars with the new moduleServer() function. Many thanks.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mod_summary_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    DT::DTOutput(ns("table"))
  )
}

mod_summary_server <- function(id){
  
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDT({ data })
    
  })
}

data <- mtcars
app_ui <- function(request) {

   mod_summary_ui("summary_ui_1")

}

app_server <- function( input, output, session ) {

  shiny::callModule(mod_summary_server,
                    "summary_ui_1")
}

shinyApp(app_ui, app_server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3245
#> Error in module(childScope$input, childScope$output, childScope, ...) : 
#>   unused arguments (childScope$output, childScope)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Is it just me or did you post a big grey pic? o_0

Comment: that came up with the reprex for some reason, can you not see the text?

Comment: The text is fine, I was just wondering, if there are some issues with my browser... or eyes...

Comment: Replace `shiny::callModule(mod_summary_server, "summary_ui_1")`  with `mod_summary_ui("summary_ui_1")`

Comment: That's the ticket, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Change the following:

```
mod_summary_server <- function(id){ 
             moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
   
   output$table <- DT::renderDT({ data })
   
 })
}
```

To as below:

```
mod_summary_server <- function(input,output,session){
    output$table <- DT::renderDT({ data })
}
```